# Constructing std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> in a range-based for-loop; is it safe to assume instances will be constructed sequentially?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr, cairo

Say that I have a bunch of classes to model text rendering; one of them manages font styling (in this case `Baz`), another is in charge of holding alignment and position info (`Foo`) and finally a class that itself renders the text using Pango, Cairo, Fontconfig, etc.

In the current iteration of this code, each instance of `Bar` creates its own `PangoContext`, `PangoLayout`, `cairo_t`, etc inside its constructor (wrapping the C APIs with smart pointers), and these are only used in the object's constructor.

A very reduced example of what I'm working with looks like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Baz {
    Baz();
    std::string aMember;
    int anotherMember;  
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(std::string const& _string, int const& _int);
};

struct Foo {
    Foo();
    void populateBar(std::vector<Baz> _bunchOfBaz);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> vectorOfBar;
};

Bar::Bar(std::string const& _string, int const& _int) {
    // Use smart pointers to set-up a pango layout and render some stuff in a cairo context.
}

void Foo::populateBar(std::vector<Baz> _bunchOfBaz) {
    vectorOfBar.clear();
    for (Baz const& _baz: _bunchOfBaz) {
        vectorOfBar.push_back(
          std::make_unique<Bar>(
            _baz.aMember,
            _baz.anotherMember
          )
        );
    }
}
```

The question is: is it guaranteed that iterations in the loop inside `populateBar` will run sequentially, and that the loop will not move on until the `Bar` constructor returns? essentially, what I want to know is: Could I keep a single instance each of `PangoLayout`, `PangoContext`, `cairo_t` etc inside `Foo` and reuse them safely for each iteration of that loop?

Comment: can `bar` constructor / copy constructor throw? If not, then it is relatively safe to assume that they will be populated sequentially.

Comment: I do not understand the part about `PangoContext` et al, but yes, iterations of the loop in `populateBar` are executed sequentially and do not interleave.

Comment: Optimizations follow the as-if rule, so the iterations may not run exactly sequentially, but if this is the case then the compiler will make sure that the observable behavior is the same _as if_ the loop ran entirely sequentially.

Comment: @Igor, I mentioned those to give better context ln exactly what I want to do, which is reduce boilerplate code.